# How to debug custom slug crashing

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework

For various reasons we have decided to try to sidestep the slug-compilation and build our own slug locally to deploy through the API (as described here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/platform-api-deploying-slugs).

The slug is built mostly like the java/scala buildpack using that buildpack jvm and is then combined with our play framework application dist file. Looking at the app dir of a normal/git-deployed app it looks aboutish the same.

Now, after deploying the slug through the api we get the expected dynos listed in the config page but the app crashes right away without giving any further information. Trying to attach a bash shell through `heroku run bash` it just times out.

Is there any way to get more information about why the app crashed out of heroku?

Comment: Did you try the logs with `heroku logs` ?

Comment: Yeah, nothing useful there at all. Tried a really basic custom slug with nothing but a shell script and am getting the same behavior. We have a ticket open with the heroku support now so we'll se if they can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after some help from heroku support we figured out the following:

The slug tar files must be created so that the paths start with './' regular relative paths doesn't cut it. When we had that figured out we didn't really have any more big problems and now we have got a working alternative build and deploy to heroku pipeline that allows us to build or app locally and then deploy that.